# Get the parent listview from a gridview object

Tags: wpf, gridview, listview, parent, visualtreehelper

In the code-behind of a WPF application I have a variable containing a GridView. I know for sure that this GridView is the View of a ListView. Is there any way to get a reference to that ListView?

Thanks

Comment: I've been trying to do the same thing recently, without success... I expected the ListView to be accessible through LogicalTreeHelper, but it isn't

Answer (score -1):

http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/02/find-wpf-parent

We've been using these helper classes for a while to find visual elements in the visual tree. In this case, you'd just want to use the method and it will hunt down the visual ancestor.

```
TryFindParent<ListView>(yourGridView);
```

Comment: That won't work, because the GridView object is not a visual child of the ListView...

Comment: So you don't have the GridView declared in code? Even if it's part of a template, you should still be able to find it through the visual tree. See this post for a method of declaring it that you could use. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ed4ab24e-28b0-49f2-986d-38bdae10051d

Comment: As I said, it is not in the visual tree. The GridView isn't even a `Visual`, it's just a kind of "descriptor" that provides a style for the view, and a method to prepare items for display. On the other hand, I would have expected it to be in the logical tree...