# WPF Get the associated ListView in a GridView

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

I'm trying to implement a custom `GridView` for the `ListView`, but I need to find a way to get the `ListView` that is associated with the `GridView`, since I need to access some of the `ListView` properties (`Width`, `Items`, `Template`...).

I found an old post that was asking the same question [Get the parent listview from a gridview object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420742/get-the-parent-listview-from-a-gridview-object) but it never got an answer...

If anyone has an idea, I would be glad :)

**EDIT:** Here some basic code from the custom `GridView`

```
public class GridViewEx : GridView
{
    public ListView Owner {get; set;}     // This is what I need to get

    public GridViewEx()
    {

    }

}
```

**EDIT2:** I found another solution than the one presented by mm8. Since I also needed a custom `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter`, which is used in the `ListView Scrollviewer Style`, here is what I came up with (as for now):

```
public class GridViewHeaderRowPresenterEx : GridViewHeaderRowPresenter
{
    private GridViewEx _GridView;

    public GridViewHeaderRowPresenterEx()
    {
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
        Unloaded += OnUnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.GetVisualParent<ListView>() is ListView lv && lv.View is GridViewEx gridView)
        {
            _GridView = gridView;
            _GridView.Owner = lv;
        }
    }

    private void OnUnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_GridView != null)
            _GridView.Owner = null;
    }
}
```

And here is the extension method to get the `ListView` from the custom `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter`:

```
public static class DependencyObjectExtensions
{
    public static T GetVisualParent<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(depObj) is DependencyObject parent)
        {
            var result = (parent as T) ?? GetVisualParent<T>(parent);
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter` `Loaded` event is called when a `GridView` is added to a `ListView`, and the `Unloaded` event is called when the `GridView` is removed from the `ListView`.

I prefer this solution over the one from mm8, since it required (if I'm not mistaken) the `ListView` to have `Items` in order to work.

Thanks for the suggestions :)

Answer (score 2):

You could override the `PrepareItem` method and use the `ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer` method to get a reference to the parent `ListView`:

```
public class GridViewEx : GridView
{
    public ListView Owner { get; set; }

    public GridViewEx()
    {

    }

    protected override void PrepareItem(ListViewItem item)
    {
        base.PrepareItem(item);
        Owner = Owner ?? ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item) as ListView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Binding** with **RelativeSource** and **AncestorType**, try the code below:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Test">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button
                                DataContext="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                                Content="Get ListView ItemsSource Count"
                                Click="Test_Click" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new List<User>
    {
        new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Mail = "john@doe-family.com" },
        new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Mail = "jane@doe-family.com" },
        new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 7, Mail = "sammy.doe@gmail.com" }
    };
}

private void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is FrameworkElement fe)
        if (fe.DataContext is List<User> users)
            MessageBox.Show($"ItemsSource items count: {users.Count()}.", "ListView Test");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I don't see how I'm suppose to access the listview from the GridView

Comment: What do you mean with "from the GridView"? Could you show me some code?